# R - Plotting a Random Subset of Data

Tags: r

I've written some code in R that generates a random selection of 20 rows from my table however I'm having trouble figuring out how to plot this random selection.

This is my plotting code:

```
plot(MyData$Corruption, MyData$MCI, ylab="MCI", xlab="Corruption",
    col=colors$color[match(MyData$Income.Level,colors$incomelevels)],
    pch=c(20),xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,110))
```

and this is the code for the random generation:

```
MyData[sample(nrow(SubMyData),20),]
```

How do I go about making sure that my plot only graphs the 20 random samples?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a small (complete) sample of your data so the problem is reproducible. Also, need to know what `SubMyData` is. That will make it possible for people to help you. Thanks :)

Comment: Is the result of `MyData[sample(nrow(SubMyData),20),]` stored anywhere? It's unclear from your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to first save the subsample to an object and then call your plotting function on that object (`my_subsample` in the example below).  Like this:

```
my_subsample <- MyData[sample(nrow(SubMyData),20),]

plot(my_subsample$Corruption, 
     my_subsample$MCI, ylab="MCI", xlab="Corruption", 
col=colors$color[match(my_subsample$Income.Level,colors$incomelevels)],
     pch=c(20),xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,110))
```

Within the call to `plot()` I just replaced `MyData` with `my_subsample` since you only want to plot the subsample.

Comment: Wow such a simple fix, I really appreciate the help - thanks!